# Visual Studio 15.7 Update: change in constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#visual-c-improvements) of the latest Visual Studio update (15.7), Microsoft states (9th bullet point):

> Inheriting a constructor now works the same as inheriting any other base class member. Previously, this worked by declaring a new constructor that delegates to the original; with this change, base class constructors are visible in a derived class as if they were derived class constructors, improving consistency in C++.

I'm slightly confused what that point actually means.

AFAIK, constructor inheritance requires an explicit `using BaseClass::BaseClass;` (since C++11):

```
struct Base
{
    Base() = default;
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}

    int x;
};

struct Derivative : Base
{
    using Base::Base;
    Derivative(int x, int y) : Base(x), y(y) {}

    int y;
};

void main()
{
    Derivative x(10);  // this is ok
}
```

My understanding of the quote is, that MS allows the constructor inheritance without the need of `using BaseClass::BaseClass;`. But testing the following code after applying the update doesn't seem to change anything in those regards:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() = default;
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}

    int x;
};

struct Derivative : Base
{   
    int y{};
};

void main()
{
    Derivative x(10);  // still illegal, compiler error
}
```

My questions are:

- What does the quote actually mean? What changed?
- How does this *improve consistency in C++* (AFAIK, the standard didn't change anything in terms of ctor inheritance)?

Comment: To me it reads as `using BaseClass::BaseClass;` now actually works in MSVS.  Unfortunately I don't have an older version I can test to see if it didn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought about that aswell, but it did work before afaik (I'm pretty sure I already used it before). [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/Kt8HJ8) says it's ok and I don't think that cl is updated to the latest version as of right now.

Comment: I think they are saying that they used to implement `using Base::Base;` by synthesizing `Derivative(int z) : Base(z) {}` constructor, but now they call `Base` constructor directly. I guess the difference is detectable by some sufficiently arcane code.

Comment: The inheriting constructor syntax has worked since VS 2015.  I interpret this the same way as @IgorTandetnik.

Comment: The [Visual C++ Team blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/) has a post about conformance, and this issue links to this [C++17 Standards working paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) which details the issue.